# How Yii2 GridView date format works

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

. Good day! Please tell me a technical question, in GridView Yii2, code:

```
  ['attribute' => 'request_date_create',
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return Yii::$app->formatter->asDateTime($model->request_date_create, 'php: d.m.Y H:i:s');
        },
    ],
```

Does it display the date 3 hours later than the one taken from the database? And this code displays normal :

```
  ['attribute' => 'request_date_create',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return Yii::$app->formatter->asDateTime(strtotime($model->request_date_create), 'php: d.m.Y H:i:s');
    },
],
```

And this code generally displays nonsense :

```
 [
    'attribute' => 'request_date_create',
    'format' => ['date', 'php: d.m.Y H:i:s']
],
```

Why? There is some nuance, but I cannot understand what

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[
    'attribute' => 'request_date_create',
    'format' => ['datetime', 'php:d.m.Y H:i:s']
],
```

Try to use `datetime` format and remove whitespace after `php:`

Looks like PHP time zone is different. See docs https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter#$defaultTimeZone-detail and example https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/684/save-and-display-datetime-fields-in-different-formats-in-yii2#tip-3-controlling-global-formats how to set formater time zone, date and time formats